# Filter data frame to keep only maximum value from each group

Tags: r

```
a <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C",2))
b <- c(1,1,2,4,1,1,2,2)
df <- data.frame(a,b)
```

But I want to keep the highest `b` value of `"A"`, `"B"`, and `"C"`.

So my new df only has 3 rows. Thank you!!!

Comment: Try `aggregate(b~a, data=df, max)`

Answer (score 1):

This is simple with `dplyr`: we just group by the value of `a` and `summarize` (for each group) the `max` value of `b`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    group_by(a) %>%
    summarize(b = max(b))

  a         b
  <fct> <dbl>
1 A         2
2 B         4
3 C         2
```

Answer (score 0):

group by a and take maximum of b

```
  df%>%
  group_by(a)%>%
  summarise(max(b))
```